# Java RabbitMQ: can't map message to corresponding class

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have two different java spring projects that communicate through rabbitmq. I'm trying to send a java object but I get this error message:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [com.thesis.gamamicroservices.productservice.dto.ProductCreatedDTO]
```

I'm aware that the problem is in the classpath that should be the same in both producer and consumer, but since each project has a different name I can't make the classpath the same even though both have the exact same class inside the same packages.

The class path is present in the header:

```
headers={__TypeId__=com.thesis.gamamicroservices.productservice.dto.ProductCreatedDTO}
```

The only difference is that the consumer app is called inventoryservice and not productservice, so it always results in conversion error.

Is there any workaround? My current provisory "solution" is using primitives or java.util classes that I later convert to the target class, but it's far from ideal since I have cases in which I need to send over 8 different types of objects, I ran out of primitives for my @RabbitHandler's...

I've also made it work by defining the target classpath in the producer but since the message is sent to multiple queues/services it's not a viable solution here.

Edit:

Here's my configuration:

Event producer:

```
@Configuration
public class EventProducerConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="productCreatedDeletedExchange")
    public Exchange createdDeletedExchange() {
       return new FanoutExchange("productCreatedDeletedExchange");
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final var rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
        Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        DefaultClassMapper classMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
        classMapper.setTrustedPackages("*");
        classMapper.setIdClassMapping(Map.of("created", ProductCreatedDTO.class));
        messageConverter.setClassMapper(classMapper);
        return messageConverter;
    }

}
```

How I send messages:

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(deletedCreatedExchange.getName(), RoutingKeys.CREATED.getNotation(), new ProductCreatedDTO(p, brand.getId(), category.getId()));
```

Event consumer:

```
@Configuration
public class EventConsumerConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="productsExchange")
    public FanoutExchange productsPubSubExchange() {
        return new FanoutExchange("productCreatedDeletedExchange");
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue productsQueue() {
        return new Queue("productsInventoryServiceQueue");
    }
    @Bean
    public Binding bindingProducts(@Qualifier("productsExchange") FanoutExchange productsExchange) {
        return BindingBuilder
                .bind(productsQueue())
                .to(productsExchange);
    }
    @Bean
    public ProductOpsReceiver productEventsReceiver() {
        return new ProductOpsReceiver();
    }
}
```

P.s.: I'm not sure if I need to define rabbitTemaplate with the message converter inside the consumer config the same way I did on the producer config, but the two apps are both a consumer and a producer so those bean are defined nonetheless.

How I receive messages:

```
@RabbitListener(queues="productsInventoryServiceQueue")
public class ProductOpsReceiver {

      @RabbitHandler
      public void productCreated(ProductCreatedDTO product) {

           logger.info(PRODUCT_CREATED_LOG, product.getId());

      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are using the `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter`.

You can add type mappings to the converter's typeMapper.

On the producer side

```
mapper.setIdClassMapping(Map.of(ProductCreatedDTO.class, "created"));
```

On the consumer side map the target class to the same token.

The type mapper will consult the map using the type id header (`created` in this case) to determine which type to use.

Comment: See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#json-message-converter

Comment: thanks for the response! yes, I'm using Jackson2JsonMessageConverter. So the type id was supposed to become "created" after setting the IdClassMapping? I added the line you wrote but the type id still is "com.thesis.gamamicroservices.productservice.dto.ProductCreatedDTO" so the error persists.

Comment: Please edit the question to show your code/configuration.

Comment: I usually use the `DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper` instead of a class mapper, but I see the `DefaultClassMapper` has similar logic; I suggest putting a breakpoint in `fromClass()` to see what's going on.

Comment: @GaryRussell DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper changed the typeid!

Comment: @GaryRussell sorry for being out of the question context, but is it possible to have multiple RabbitHandler's receiving the same object type? If so, how do I differentiate them? Otherwise, I will have to encapsulate different classes with the same properties...

Comment: It's better to ask a new question - a comment doesn't help people find questions/answers. No; the payload type is used to chose the method we call; you will get this error `throw new AmqpException("Ambiguous methods for payload type: " + payloadClass + ": " + result.getMethod().getName() + " and " + handler.getMethod().getName());`

Comment: *"On the consumer side map the target class to the same token."* How can we do this?

Comment: `mapper.setIdClassMapping(Map.of(ConsumerSideDTO.class, "created"));`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. After investigating, I found that we can add the annotation @Payload to your parameter. With this annotation, this parameter will be treated as **inferredType**. And the priority of inferredType is higher than `__TypeId__`

I think this is a better solution.

Related source code:

```java
@Override
    public JavaType toJavaType(MessageProperties properties) {
        //inferredType
        JavaType inferredType = getInferredType(properties);
        if (inferredType != null && canConvert(inferredType)) {
            return inferredType;
        }

        String typeIdHeader = retrieveHeaderAsString(properties, getClassIdFieldName());

        if (typeIdHeader != null) {
            return fromTypeHeader(properties, typeIdHeader);
        }

        if (hasInferredTypeHeader(properties)) {
            return fromInferredTypeHeader(properties);
        }

        return TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(Object.class);
    }
```